# How many $k$-APs passing two fixed numbers in $\mathbb{Z}_N$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory

For an positive integer $N$, $k$-set $\{a,a+d,a+2d,\dots,a+(k-1)d\}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}_N$ is called a $k$-term arithmetic progression in $\mathbb{Z}_N$.

I am wondering given distinct $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_N$, at most how many $(k-1)$-sets $S\subseteq\mathbb{Z}_N$ so that $\{x\}\cup S$ and $\{y\}\cup S$ are both $k$-term arithmetic progressions? Is $k^2$ an upper bound? My intuition is that given the places of $x,y$, the arithmetic progressions may be determined uniquely?